# why only MainThread reaches my function?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

```
import threading
```

in this function I want to do my coding stuff for each thread but only mainthread enters this function none of thread which has been created in main function enters this function

```
def enrich():
    for i in range(10):
        print(threading.current_thread().getName())



def main():
    Thread_0 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_3 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_4 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_5 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_6 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
    Thread_7 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())

    Thread_0.setName('0')
    Thread_1.setName('1')
    Thread_2.setName('2')
    Thread_3.setName('3')
    Thread_4.setName('4')
    Thread_5.setName('5')
    Thread_6.setName('6')
    Thread_7.setName('7')

    Thread_0.start()
    Thread_1.start()
    Thread_2.start()
    Thread_3.start()
    Thread_4.start()
    Thread_5.start()
    Thread_6.start()
    Thread_7.start()

    Thread_0.join()
    Thread_1.join()
    Thread_2.join()
    Thread_3.join()
    Thread_4.join()
    Thread_5.join()
    Thread_6.join()
    Thread_7.join()
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

in output I get this :

```
C:\Users\Danial\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe "D:/iaun/Final Project/FileTermsInfo/test.py"
MainThread
MainThread
MainThread
MainThread
MainThread
MainThread
MainThread
MainThread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Thread_0 = threading.Thread(target=enrich())
```

Here you are *calling* your `enrich()` function rather than passing a reference to that function into the `Thread` constructor. Naturally this happens on the main thread because there aren't any other threads yet. The function returns `None` so you are actually specifying `target=None` in the constructor and none of your threads receive a reference to the function to be called. As a result, none of them do anything. All the calls to `enrich()` occur before even a single a thread is created and they occur sequentially, not in parallel.

Pass the function, not its result:

```
Thread_0 = threading.Thread(target=enrich)
```

And likewise for your other threads.

Also, sheesh, use a list rather than individual variables for the threads. There is no reason for all that code to do what you could do in a handful of lines.

```
threads = [threading.Thread(target=enrich, name=str(x)) for x in range(8)]
for thread in threads: 
    thread.start()
for thread in threads: 
    thread.join()
```

Comment: thanks a lot kindall I want to be sure that I'm doing everythings right that's why I didn't use list

Comment: what about the situation when I want to pass some variables as input to the function?

Comment: That's what the `args` argument of the constructor is for. Or in some cases it might be more convenient to use a lambda or `functools.partial`.

Comment: u mean I should do something like this : threading.Thread(target=enrich, name=str(x), args=(a,b))

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking.